# DropDownList duplicate items

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am trying to rebind data to a `DataList` that get's it's data from an `SqlDataSource` but I keep getting duplicate items. Here is my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="CategoryDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryName] FROM [forum_categories]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void Button6_Click( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    string categoryToCreate = CreateCategory.Text;

    if(categoryToCreate != string.Empty)
    {
        CategoryCreateName.Visible = false;
        DataAccess.insertDataItem(categoryToCreate);
        CategoryList.DataBind(); 
    }
    else
    {
        CategoryCreateName.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

The *insertDataItem* inserts a new category into the database.

How can I update the items in the `DropDownList` so that I do not get duplicate items?

Comment: You might check on whether you have the `AppendDataBoundItems` property set to True.  That will cause each successive DataBind to add the items to the DropDownList rather than clearing it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    protected void Button6_Click( object sender , EventArgs e )
{
    string categoryToCreate = CreateCategory.Text;

    if(categoryToCreate != string.Empty)
    {
        CategoryCreateName.Visible = false;
        DataAccess.insertDataItem(categoryToCreate);
        CategoryList.Items.Clear();
        CategoryList.DataBind(); 
    }else
    {
        CategoryCreateName.Visible = true;
    }
}
```